# How to get facebook likes using Facebook sdk4.0 in android?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-studio, facebook-sdk-4.0

```
  Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                // response should have the likes
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
        Request request = new Request(session, "me/likes", null, HttpMethod.GET, callback);
        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();``
```

**I am trying to get facebook likes using facebook sdk using this code But it is not working.Is there any other way to get it?**

Comment: Did you check the answer @Rituraj Singh Rathore

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this code [link](https://github.com/socioboard/f-board/tree/master/Android/f-boardpro)

it will help you out